# Handling filtering by a particular field in JPA Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I want to implement a filtering feature based on the properties of an entity that I have stored in my db.
I'm using a JPA query to do so. The problem that I'm facing is concerned with entity manager which requires the class of the object that is required to return.

```
public List<CountryEntity> getSortedCountries(String field, String type) {
        return entityManager.createQuery(GET_ALL_SORTED.concat(field).concat(" " + type), CountryEntity.class).getResultList();
    }
```

When I select only one field, let's say the name of the country, the query returns a String and not an object of type CountryEntity.
What is the best approach to handle this problem? Should I create classes for every single case or is there another way that I'm missing?

Comment: 'When I select only one field, let's say the name of the country, the query returns a String and not an object of type CountryEntity' - I'm confused, what behaviour did you expect? Please post the relevant query as well

Comment: "SELECT country FROM CountryEntity country ORDER BY country.name

Comment: You said 'When I select only one field'. The above query selects the entire entity

Comment: I want to get a subset of the country fields and return them as a response to the client. The problem is that createQuery requires you to specify the class of the type of entity that you expect from the query result.

Comment: You can use the `NEW` operator, then: `SELECT NEW my.package.CountryProjection(name, population, ...) FROM ...`